# Changing table info with Rails migration

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, migration

In my original migration, I had this:

```
create_table :credit_purchases do |t|
  t.column :amount, :decimal, :precision => 8, :scale => 2, :null => false
  t.column :time, :datetime, :null => false
end
```

Which produced the following MySQL table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE `credit_purchases` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `amount` decimal(8,2) NOT NULL,
  `time` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
)
```

When I run this, it doesn't change the definition at all:

```
change_column :credit_purchases, :amount, :decimal, :precision => 8, :scale => 2
change_column :credit_purchases, :time, :datetime
```

I'd expect the definition result to be:

```
CREATE TABLE `credit_purchases` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `amount` decimal(8,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
)
```

What do I have to do to produce the desired result?  I want to avoid defining DB constraints via the migration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try explicitly adding `:null => true`.

Comment: Yea, that will work, but trying to avoid specifying DB constraints in migration.

Comment: Why does specifying `:null => true` fix the problem, though?

Comment: Migrations are a rather transient thing to be so particular about.  If you want to avoid using DB contraints (instead, preferring model constraints) that's a perfectly valid philosophy, and adding `:null => true` will get you back on track there.  If you want your schema.rb to be free of the `:null => true` marker, I'm guessing that if you apply the migration with `:null => true` and then yet another migration without it, schema.rb will probably be "free" of any `:null` markers.

Comment: Fantastic. Really appreciate you taking the time annotate your original answer. Also appreciate the philosophical adjustment!